# Browser-sync doesn't update the ng-model correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, browser-sync

I have some problem using browser-sync with angular js, here's my question. I successfully sync the click and scroll events with browser-sync, but not the input fields. Although the "text" in the input field is updated, the ng-model bind to the field is not.

For example, when I type "abc" in chrome, the corresponding field in firefox shows "abc" too, but the model value doesn't get "abc" at all, so the next operation in firefox will base on a empty value which leads to a wrong result.

Another example is, I use angular-strap for my dropdown list, when I click a list to collapse in chrome, the list in firefox doesn't collapse at all. I think this is because the click event has been handled by angular-strap so the browser-sync can catch it.

What should I do to make the browser-sync and ng-model works together? Please give me some advises, thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue with Angular 5. Did you find any solution for this?